# run grafana-agent through docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, grafana-agent

I found information about grafana-agent on the Grafana website. It shows how to run it in docker.

- **linux**

```yaml
docker run \
  -v WAL_DATA_DIRECTORY:/etc/agent/data \
  -v CONFIG_FILE_PATH:/etc/agent/agent.yaml \
  grafana/agent:v0.39.0
```

- Windows

```yaml
docker run ^
  -v WAL_DATA_DIRECTORY:C:\etc\grafana-agent\data ^
  -v CONFIG_FILE_PATH:C:\etc\grafana-agent ^
  grafana/agent:v0.39.0-windows
```

It turned out to expand like this (one line command):

```yaml
docker run -v WAL_DATA_DIRECTORY:/etc/grafana-agent/data -v CONFIG_FILE_PATH:/etc/grafana-agent   grafana/agent:v0.39.0
```

[image]

Can you do that?

docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  grafana-agent:
    container_name: grafana-agent
    image: grafana/agent:v0.39.0
    environment:
      WAL_DATA_DIRECTORY: "/etc/agent/data" 
      CONFIG_FILE_PATH:  "/etc/agent/agent.yaml"
    volumes:
      - ./data/:/etc/agent/data
      - ./agent.yaml/:/etc/agent/agent.yaml
  restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - grafana

networks:
  grafana:
    driver: bridge
```

But why is the port not specified?

- agent.yaml

```yaml
metrics:
  wal_directory: /etc/agent/data
  global:
    remote_write:
      - url: http://localhost:9009/api/prom/push

integrations:
  agent:
    enabled: true
```

I don't quite understand why there is such a difference for Windows and Linux (except because of the differences in mounting directories on the host system inside the docker container).

I tried to run this command on a Windows system, but it didn't work.  However, the question is how to make a universal docker-compose configuration file, by running which you could deploy grafana-agent. In addition, I did not understand on which port grafana-agent should be deployed and how to transfer the configuration file to it for integrations with various systems (for example, for prometheus).

The above configuration, through linking a directory and a file in the host system inside the container, seems to be supposed to accomplish the task, but did I do it right?